# Generics, Type Parameters and Wildcards

Tags: java, generics, types, wildcard

I am trying to understand java generics and they seem extremely difficult to understand. For example, this is fine...

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<?> list = null;
        method(list);
    }

    public static <T> void method(List<T> list) { }
}
```

... as is this...

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<List<?>> list = null;
        method(list);
    }

    public static <T> void method(List<T> list) { }
}
```

... and this ...

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<List<List<?>>> list = null;
        method(list);
    }

    public static <T> void method(List<List<T>> list) { }
}
```

... but this doesn't compile:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<List<?>> list = null;
        method(list);
    }

    public static <T> void method(List<List<T>> list) { }
}
```

Can someone explain what is going on in simple language?

Comment: Just curious, was Boris' answer sufficient, or are you still iffy on this?

Comment: @Radiodef I'm not iffy on this at all now. It took a while but I finally got it. I've been answering loads of generics questions since I wrote this question!

Comment: Alright, no problem. ; ) I saw the comments and thought about writing something additional. It's not often this comes up. [*"Capture conversion is not applied recursively."*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.10) Only the wildcard in the first example can be captured.

Comment: @Radiodef The key for me was when I finally grasped that `List<?>` is a type (whereas `?` isn't). So `List<List<?>>` means a `List` whose elements have the type `List<?>`, whereas `List<?>` means a `List` of some unknown type.

Comment: Yes, and the nature of the error here is that: if you have a `List<?>` the `?` can be *treated* like a type (captured) as in the first example. But if you have some nested type like `Map<?, List<?>>`, only a wildcard in the "outermost" type (so the `Map` but not the `List`) can be captured. Boris' answer demonstrates *why* (we could do unsafe stuff) but not the particulars of the *how* (capture). A wildcard has slightly different semantics, depending on if it's in an "outer" or "inner" type.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The main thing to understand with generic types, is that they aren't covariant.

So whilst you can do this:

```
final String string = "string";
final Object object = string;
```

The following will not compile:

```
final List<String> strings = ...
final List<Object> objects = strings;
```

This is to avoid the situations where you circumvent the generic types:

```
final List<String> strings = ...
final List<Object> objects = strings;
objects.add(1);
final String string = strings.get(0); <-- oops
```

So, going through your examples one by one

### 1

Your generic method takes a `List<T>`, you pass in a `List<?>`; which is (essentially) a `List<Object>`. `T` can be assigned to the `Object` type and the compiler is happy.

### 2

Your generic method is the same, you pass in a `List<List<?>>`. `T` can be assigned to the `List<?>` type and the compiler is again happy.

### 3

This is basically the same as **2** with another level of nesting. `T` is still the `List<?>` type.

### 4

Here is where it goes a little pear shaped, and where my point from above comes in.

Your generic method takes a `List<List<T>>`. You pass in a `List<List<?>>`. Now, as generic types are not covariant, `List<?>` cannot be assigned to a `List<T>`.

The actual compiler error (Java 8) is:

> required: `java.util.List<java.util.List<T>>`   found:
>   `java.util.List<java.util.List<?>>`   reason: cannot infer
>   type-variable(s) `T`
>       (argument mismatch; `java.util.List<java.util.List<?>>` cannot be converted to `java.util.List<java.util.List<T>>`)

Basically the compiler is telling you that it cannot find a `T` to assign because of having to infer the type of the `List<T>` nested in the outer list.

Lets look at this in a little more detail:

`List<?>` is a `List` of *some unknown type* - it could be a `List<Integer>` or a `List<String>`; we can `get` from it as `Object`, **but we cannot `add`**. Because otherwise we run into the covariance issue I mentioned.

`List<List<?>>` is a `List` of `List` of some unknown type - it could be a `List<List<Integer>>` or a `List<List<String>>`. In case **1** it was possible to assign `T` to `Object` and just not allow `add` operations on wildcard list. In case **4** this cannot be done - primarily because there is not a generics construct to prevent `add` to the outer `List`.

If the compiler were to assign `T` to `Object` in the second case then something like the following would be possible:

```
final List<List<Integer>> list = ...
final List<List<?>> wildcard = list;
wildcard.add(Arrays.asList("oops"));
```

So, due to covariance, it is not possible to assign a `List<List<Integer>>` to *any other* generic `List` safely.

Comment: This is almost convincing me. The only quibble is in example 1 when you say T can be assigned to the Object type. That doesn't seem right to me - it doesn't work if you replace the method by a non-generic method taking a List<Object>. Surely in example 1 the compiler is able to see that a type T can be found to match a List<?> to a List<T>. Why can't the compiler see the same thing in example 4?

Comment: Same here - it sounds convincing, but ... not completely: You can call the last method when explicitly passing in a `List<List<Object>>`, so the argument should not be referring to missing covariance, but rather to a weakness of the type inference system and the wildcard that is involved there....

Comment: Don't you mean `objects.add(1);`?

Comment: @pbabcdefp added a clarifying edit - hopefully that explains the issue more clearly.

Comment: Some things that are prevented are without risk of the exceptions you mention. E.g. if I have a method with signature `static <T> List<List<T>> m1(List<T> a)` and another one with signature `static <T> void m2(List<List<T>> a)`, you will find that if `x` is of type `List<?>` then `m2(m1(x))` doesn't compile! The value returned by a method returning a `List<List<T>>` isn't accepted as a parameter to a method with an argument of type `List<List<T>>`. But `m2(m1(x))` is risk-free - you can write a method with parameter `List<T>` whose body is `m2(m1(x));` and it accepts a `List<?>` just fine.

Comment: Actually I'm wrong... `m2(m1(x))` executes fine. But IntelliJ doesn't realise it's going to, and issues the error message method2(java.util.List<T>) cannot be applied to method2(java.util.List<?>). If the authors of IntelliJ don't understand this stuff, what hope do the rest of us have?

Comment: @pbabcdefp I use IntelliJ - it does have some issues with type inference. I recommend that you log it as a bug - help the community out!