# Java: How to pass 2 dimensional ArrayList to a method/constructor

Tags: java, arraylist, constructor

I am trying to pass a 2d ArrayList to a constructor. The header of the constructor is as such:

```
public Table( ArrayList<ArrayList<?>> table )
{
```

After this I am trying to implement the following code in main:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>> 2dList = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>>(2); 

Table Data1 = new Table( 2dList );
```

However, when I attempt such code I receive the following error:

```
no suitable contructor found for Table(java.util.ArrayList<java.util.ArrayList<java.lang.Object>>)
    constructor Table.Table(java.util.ArrayList<java.util.ArrayList<?>>) is not applicable
    (argument mismatch; java.util.ArrayList<java.util.ArrayList<java.lang.Object>> cannot be converted to java.util.ArrayList<java.util.ArrayList<?>>)
```

What would be the correct implementation? Forgive me if I have misunderstood any basic idea or have made a silly mistake.

Thank You.

Comment: Replace `?` with `Object`?

Comment: No, you're not making a silly mistake. Generics are totally baffling. I encountered this the other day (See http://stackoverflow.com/q/27465348/3973077). You can make it work by writing `Table(ArrayList<? extends ArrayList<?>> table)`, but mere mortals aren't meant to understand why.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An `ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>>` is not an `ArrayList<ArrayList<?>>`, even though an `ArrayList<Object>` is an `ArrayList<?>`, [for the same reason that a `List<Dog>` is not a `List<Animal>`, even if a `Dog` is an `Animal`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-arent-javas-generics-implicitly-p).

To pass an `ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>>`, include another wildcard in the signature:

```
public Table( ArrayList<? extends ArrayList<?>> table )
```

Comment: I went back and looked over the wildcard implementation and the inheritance concept and now it makes complete sense to me. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Variable names cannot start with numbers! `2dList` should be `list2D` or something like that

Also declare your constructor like so

```
public Table(ArrayList<? extends ArrayList<?>> list2D) {

}
```

Or like this

```
public <E> Table(ArrayList<ArrayList<E>> list2D) {

}
```