# Parameterization Well Formedness and Capture Conversion in Java

Tags: java, generics, compiler-errors, java-8, wildcard

Given the following two class definitions:

```
class C1<T extends C1<T>> {}

class C2<U> extends C1<C2<U>> {}
```

And the following type declaration:

```
C1<C2<?>> a;
```

Intuitively it feels the declared type `a` should be valid, but this is not the way JDK-8u45 behaves. Instead we get something like the following output:

```
Test.java:3: error: type argument C2<?> is not within bounds of type-variable T
        C1<C2<?>> a;
             ^
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends C1<T> declared in class C1
1 error
```

(**Edit:** I was being a dingus here, this part has been answered: `C2<?>` *does not* extend `C1<C2<?>>`. The issue regarding the declaration of `c` below is still an open question, though.)

But `C2<?>` *does* extend `C1<C2<?>>`, which would appear to trivially satisfy the bound. Examination of the [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.5) provides no further illumination so far as I can see. It really should just be as simple as satisfying the bound by the subtype relation, since `C2<?>` is not a wildcard type and therefore capture conversion is just an identity conversion on the argument.

There are situations where it becomes a little less clear, for example, take the following class definitions:

```
class C3<T extends C3<?>> {}

class C4<Y, Z> extends C3<C4<Z, Y>> {}

class C5<X extends C3<X>> {
    void accept(X x);
}
```

All of this is fine, but then if we try the following declaration:

```
C5<C6<?, ?>> b;
```

Things become stranger. `C6<?, ?>` is a subtype of `C3<C6<?, ?>>`, so the declaration should be valid according to my interpretation of the specification as given above regarding the declaration `C1<C2<?>>`. The problem is that clearly not every possible subtype of `C6<?, ?>` actually satisfies that bound, so now for example `C5.accept()` resolves its parameter type to `C6<?, ?>` and so can accept arguments which violate the bounding on `X`, i.e. any where the parameterizations of `Y` and `Z` are not identical.

Where am I going wrong here? Is my understanding of the subtype relationship insufficient?

(**Edit:** The following part of the question is still unanswered, but I've moved it to a new question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30788366/capture-conversion-issue-in-java-wrt-reconciliation-of-jls-and-actual-jdk-behav) since it's a completely different issue really... Sorry for making a mess and not using the site very well haha...)

Aside from this, I'm also having some problems with capture conversion in similar situations. Take the following type declaration:

```
C1<? extends C2<?>> c;
```

Unlike the similar declaration `a` at the start, this compiles fine in JDK-8u45. If we examine the [specification for capture conversion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.10), though, it appears this declaration *should* result in a compile time error this time.

In particular, the upper bound of the new type variable capture `CAP#T` is given by `glb(Bi, Ui[A1:=S1,...,An:=Sn])`, where in this case `Bi` resolves to the wildcard bound `C2<?>` and `Ui[A1:=S1,...,An:=Sn]` resolves to `C1<CAP#T>`.

From this, `glb(C2<?>, C1<CAP#T>)` resolves to the intersection type `C2<?> & C1<CAP#T>`, which is invalid, because `C2<?>` and `C1<CAP#T>` are both class types, not interface types, but neither one of them is a subtype of the other.

This (apparent) rule violation is made more clear in the [definition of the intersection type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.9) itself.

I'm sure it's not a bug and I'm just making some simple mistakes somewhere... but if nobody here can shed any light on this for me I'll try the compiler-dev mailing list or something.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: It's a fascinating issue. I'm just curious, is this some theoretical problem you have or do you have some real world classes for this? I just can't imagine where one would use  `class C1<T extends C1<T>> {}` or `class C2<U> extends C1<C2<U>> {}`.

Comment: Valid question! I have no specific real world application of this particular issue... But I *do* need to understand the proper expected behaviour, as I'm writing a bunch of reflective utilities over the type system and want the behaviour to match the spec/JDK. Currently it's mostly working, including type inference of generic method invocation, but there are a couple of edge cases (like this one) which cause issues. If you want to take a look it's hosted here: https://github.com/StrangeSkies/uk.co.strangeskies. No wiki yet, but the javadocs are all present for the `.reflection` package.

Comment: This actually has very little to do with capture conversion. Instead, you should look in 4.10.2 and 4.5.1 for answers. You're being misled as long as you view this as related to capture conversion. For example, your reasoning for why `C1<? extends C2<?>>` shouldn't compile is nonsense. (I think it's also wrong, I don't think there is an intersection type if capture conversion *were* applied, because [capture conversion would not be applied recursively](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30385343/2891664) but I just woke up so I'm a bit groggy.)

Comment: I know the first part has nothing to do with capture conversion, but the declaration of `c` does. And I didn't apply it recursively, I only applied it to `C<T1,...,Tn>` to give `C<X1,...,Xn>` as described in sec. 4.5. Because the type argument is a wildcard with an upper bound, and the type parameter itself also has an upper bound, the resulting upper bound is the intersection type of those two bounds: "If `Ti` is a wildcard type argument of the form `? extends Bi`, then `Si` is a fresh type variable whose upper bound is `glb(Bi, Ui[A1:=S1,...,An:=Sn])` and whose lower bound is the null type."

Comment: I also have looked through 4.10.2 and 4.5.1 before a number of times, but I cannot see where they contradict the analysis I gave in my question regarding the declarations `a` and `b`. If you could point out where they do when you're less groggy, I would be very grateful, thanks!

Comment: @Radiodef thanks again for the help. bayou.io has clarified in an answer what my silly mistake was wrt the first part of the question, and I've marked that answer as correct and separated the capture conversion issue into another question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30788366/capture-conversion-issue-in-java-wrt-reconciliation-of-jls-and-actual-jdk-behav

It should be more clear there that recursive capture conversion is not the issue, as I have swapped out the inner wildcard with a class type, and the question essentially remains identical.

Comment: Interesting - IntelliJ 14.1.3 does not show an error for this, while `javac` does. Created an [IntelliJ bug report](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-141388).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While 
`C2<x> extends C1<C2<x>>` for any reference type `x`, 
it is not the case that 
`C2<?> extends C1<C2<?>>`

A wildcard `?` is **not a type**. It is a *type argument*. The syntax though is very deceiving (by design).

Let's use a different syntax - if there's any 1st-level wildcard, use `{}` instead of `<>`, e.g.

```
List{?},  Map{String, ? extends Number}
```

The meaning of `{?}` is to declare a union type

```
List{? extends Number}  ==  union of List<Number>, List<Integer>, List<Long>, ....
```

It's easy to see that, `List<Integer>` is a subtype of  `List{? extends Number}`; and 
 `List{? extends Number}` is a subtype of `List{? extends Object}`

However, there's no way that `Foo{?}` is a subtype of a `Foo<x>`.

---

In our syntax, `<>` is reserved for substituting type vars with **types**. So we write 
`List<String>, C2<Integer>`, etc. It's easy to understand their meaning - just replace `T`'s with `String` in the source code of `List`, we get a  good-old plain class.

```
    interface List<String>
        String get(int)
```

This cannot be done for wildcard - it makes no sense

```
    interface List<?>
        ? get(int)
```

So it is not allowed to `new ArrayList{?}()`, or `class MyList implements List{?}`

So, how can we use `List{?}`? What methods we can call on it?

When the type of an *expression* is a `List{?}`, we know that it is an object, and the object must belong to a subclass of `List<x>` for some unknown **type** `x`. This is *wildcard capture*

```
obj is a List{?}  =>  obj is a List<x>, where x a subtype of Object.
```

Even though the exact type of `x` is unknown at compile time, we can still do the substitution

```
    interface List<x>
        x get(int)
```

so we can make sense of the call `obj.get(0)`; it returns `x`, and `x` is a subtype of `Object`; so we can assign the return value to an `Object`.

Comment: Ah yes, right you are, that was a bit of a brain fart on my part. Thanks very much! Any thoughts on the `C1<? extends C2<?>> c;` issue with intersection type on the upper bound? I think that might be a little more tricky, but maybe not...

Comment: I've put the second part of the question into a new question so I can just mark your answer as correct and get rid of all the cruft, since the second part is basically a completely separate issue. The new question is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30788366/capture-conversion-issue-in-java-wrt-reconciliation-of-jls-and-actual-jdk-behav