# Capture conversion issue in Java, WRT reconciliation of JLS and actual JDK behaviour

Tags: java, generics, compiler-errors, wildcard

Given the following two class definitions:

```
class C1<T extends C1<T>> {}

class C2<U> extends C1<C2<U>> {}
```

Consider the following type declaration:

```
C1<? extends C2<String>> c;
```

This compiles fine in JDK-8u45, but if we examine the [specification for capture conversion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.10), it appears (to me) that this declaration *should* result in a compile time error.

In particular, the upper bound of the new type variable capture `T#1` is given by `glb(Bi, Ui[A1:=S1,...,An:=Sn])`, where in this case `Bi` resolves to the wildcard bound `C2<String>` and `Ui[A1:=S1,...,An:=Sn]` resolves to `C1<T#1>`.

From this, `glb(C2<?>, C1<T#1>)` resolves to the intersection type `C2<String> & C1<T#1>`, which is invalid, because `C2<String>` and `C1<T#1>` are both class types, not interface types, but neither one of them is a subtype of the other.

This (apparent) rule violation is perhaps made more clear in the [definition of the intersection type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.9) itself.

<del>I'm sure it's not a bug and I'm just making some simple mistakes somewhere...</del> If it is a bug, I hope it can be considered a bug in the JLS and not the JDK, such that I can expect to be able to safely emulate the behaviour...

Thanks for any help!

**Edit:** After talking with Radiodef yesterday I convinced myself that the issue (or one way of looking at it at least) is that `C2<String>` *can effectively be thought of* as a subtype of `C1<T#1>`, since T#1 can only *ever* be satisfied by `C2<String>` and so can be considered equal to it, but the containment and subtyping rules have no understanding of this relationship as written, and so the JLS will not recognise the subtype and should fail...

If you take the slightly more complex case of `C1<? extends C2<?>> d;`, though, it is more tricky. The problem is similar, but the intersection type which forms the upper bound on the capture comes out as `C2<?> & C1<T#2>`, where it doesn't seem a solution can be arrived at by the same reasoning as above.

Comment: I may take a closer look at this problem later; but off the top of my head, JLS#4.9 seems quite problematic. I once asked Dan Smith and he said this area is poorly specified.

Comment: I agree with your interpretation. I posted the question to compiler-dev: http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/compiler-dev/2015-June/009604.html

Comment: I'm also beginning to agree this is iffy. I think you should unaccept my answer, at least the way it is now.

Comment: Maurizio's response - http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/compiler-dev/2015-June/009621.html

Comment: Dan Smith - https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8054937

Comment: Thanks for the discussion and interest from everyone, much appreciated! Very interested in how the spec might evolve in the future here, as touched upon in Maurizio's response. Cheers.

Comment: Can you answer your own question and accept it as a correct answer? Otherwise it will be shown as unanswered and will attract more people who want to help. In any case, what you found out deserves the reputation points of an accepted answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is answered best by [Maurizio's response on compiler-dev](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/compiler-dev/2015-June/009621.html).

(TL;DR javac is indeed out of alignment with the spec here, and the optimal solution probably lies somewhere between the two approaches)

An associated bug [can be found here](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8054937).

Many thanks to all who contributed to this answer.