# Java: Covariant Wildcard Bounds in Method parameters

Tags: java, generics, covariance

I am confused about the rules around wildcard bounds.  It seems that sometimes it is OK to declare a method parameter whose bound does not satisfy the bound declared by the class.  In the below code, method foo(...) compiles fine but bar(...) does not.  I don't understand why either one is allowed.

```
public class TestSomething {
    private static class A<T extends String> {}

    public static void foo(A<? extends Comparable<?>> a) {

    }

    public static void bar(A<? extends Comparable<Double>> a) {

    }
}
```

Comment: think about `class A<T extends Pet>` and `A<? extends Runnable>`. It is ok, because there could be a class, e.g. `Dog`, that is both a `Pet` and `Runnable`.

Comment: But in my example there also could be a class that extends String and implements Comparable<Double> - yet bar produces a compile error.  If my intention was to allow this, then shouldn't I have to declare the parameter as A<? extends String & Comparable<Double>>?

Comment: `String implements Comparable<String>`. you cannot have a class implementing both `Comparable<String> and Comparable<Double>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a question of when parameterized types are "well-formed", i.e. what type arguments are allowed. The JLS isn't very well written on this topic, and compilers are doing things out of spec. 
The following is my understanding. (per JLS8, oracle javac 8)

In general we talk about generic class/interface declaration `G<T extends B1>`; as an example

```
    class Foo<T extends Number> { .. }
```

A generic declaration can be seen as a declaration of a set of concrete types; e.g. `Foo` declares types `Foo<Number>, Foo<Integer>, Foo<Float>, ...`

#### no wildcard

A concrete type `G<X>` (where X is a type) is well-formed iff `X<:B1`, i.e. `X` is a subtype of `B1`.

- `Foo<Integer>` is well-formed because `Integer<:Number`.
- `Foo<String>` is not well-formed; it doesn't exist in the type system.

This constraint is enforced rigorously, for example, this won't compile

```
    <T> void m1(Foo<T> foo)  // Error, it's not the case that T<:Number
```

#### ? super

Given a type `G<? super B2>`, we would expect that `B2<:B1`. This is because we most often need to apply capture conversion on it, resulting in `G<X> where B2<:X<:B1`, implying `B2<:B1`. If `B2<:B1` is false, we'll introduce contradiction in the type system, leading to bizzare behaviors.

In fact, `Foo<? super String>` is rejected by javac, which is nice, because the type is apparently a programmer's error.

Interestingly, we cannot find this constraint in JLS; or at least, it is not clearly stated in JLS. And experiments show that `javac` does not always enforce this constraint, for example

```
    <T> Foo<? super T> m2()  // compiles, even though T<:Number is false

    <String>m2();  // compiles! returns Foo<? super String> !
```

It's unclear why they are allowed. I'm not aware of any problem this would cause in practice though.

#### ? extends

Given `G<? extends B2>`, capture conversion yields `G<X> where X<:B1&B2`.

The question is when the intersection type `B1&B2` is well-formed. The most liberal approach would be to allow any intersection; even if the intersection is empty, i.e. `B1&B2` is equivalent to the null type, it won't cause problems in the type system.

But practically, we would want the compiler to reject things like `Number&String`, introduced by `Foo<? extends String>`, since in all likelihood it must be a programmer's error.

A more specific reason is that `javac` needs to construct a "notional class" that is a subtype of `B1&B2` so that javac can reason about what methods can be called on the type. For that purpose, `Number&String` cannot be allowed, while `Number&Integer`, `Number&Object`, `Number&Runnable` etc are allowed. This part is specified in [JLS#4.9](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.9)

`String & Comparable<Double>` cannot be allowed, because the notional class would be implementing both `Comparable<String>` and `Comparable<Double>`, which is illegal in Java.

`B1` and `B2` can be in many forms, leading to more complicated cases. This is where the spec isn't very well thought out. For example, it's unclear, from the text of the spec, what if one of them is a type variable; the behavior of `javac` does seem reasonable to us

```
    <T extends Runnable> Foo<? extends T> m3()  // error
    <T extends Object  > Foo<? extends T> m4()  // error
    <T extends Number  > Foo<? extends T> m5()  // ok
    <T extends Integer > Foo<? extends T> m6()  // ok
```

Another example, should `Number & Callable<?>` be allowed? And if it is, what should be the notional class's super interfaces? Remember that `Callable<?>` cannot be a super interface

```
    class Bar extends Number implements Callable<?> // illegal
```

In an even more complicated [case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30788366) we have something like `Foo<Number> & Foo<CAP#1>` where `CAP#1` is a type variable introduced by capture conversion. The spec clearly forbids it, yet the use case indicates that it should be legitimate.

`javac` handles these cases more liberally than JLS. See responses from [Maurizio](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/compiler-dev/2015-June/009621.html) and [Dan](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8054937)

#### ? ? ?

So, what do we do about it as a programmer? - Follow your intuition and construct types that make sense to you. Most likely `javac` would accept it. If not, it's probably a mistake on your part. In rare cases, the type makes sense, yet the spec/javac doesn't allow it; you are out of luck:) and you'll  have to find workarounds.

Answer (score 6):

Let's first consider method `void foo(A<? extends Comparable<?>> a)`. `A<? extends Comparable<?>>` is "compatible" with `A<T extends String>` because  there exists a wildcard type `P`, and a comparable wildcard type `Q` to satisfy the following:

```
P <: Comparable<Q> && P <: String
```

Since `String <: Comparable<String>`, `Q` must be `String`, and `P` may be any sub-type of `String` (which since String is declared `final`, your options are limited)

Now let's consider method `void bar(A<? extends Comparable<Double>> a)`. There is no wildcard type `P` that can satisfy

```
P <: Comparable<Double> && P <: String
```

because String has already implemented `Comparable<String>` which is not a `Comparable<Double>`, and it's impossible for any subclass of `String` to implement `Comparable<Double>`.

Just because you've written a signature `A<? extends Comparable<?>> a` doesn't mean that you can pass the method any `A<? extends Comparable<?>>`. You could change the declaration to accept any `A<? extends Object>` and it will compile too, but you can only instantiate `A<T extends String>`, so it isn't a loophole around having to use String or its subclasses.

Interestingly enough my Eclipse IDE doesn't even find the compile error in bar as declared above, but it does if bar accepts `A<? extends Integer>` for example.

See [this part](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.5.1) of the Java specification for a complete understanding.

> Two type arguments are provably distinct if one of the following is true:

- Neither argument is a type variable or wildcard, and the two arguments are not the same type.
- One type argument is a type variable or wildcard, with an upper bound (from capture conversion, if necessary) of S; and the other type argument T is not a type variable or wildcard; and neither |S| <: |T| nor |T| <: |S|.
- **Each type argument is a type variable or wildcard, with upper bounds (from capture conversion, if necessary) of S and T; and neither |S| <: |T| nor |T| <: |S|.**

> A type argument T1 is said to contain another type argument T2, written T2 <= T1, if the set of types denoted by T2 is provably a subset of the set of types denoted by T1 under the reflexive and transitive closure of the following rules (where <: denotes subtyping (§4.10)):

```
? extends T <= ? extends S if T <: S
? super T <= ? super S if S <: T
T <= T
T <= ? extends T
T <= ? super T
```

Comment: > A<? extends Comparable<?>> is compatible with A<T extends String> because String implements Comparable<String> which is a Comparable<?>.  I don't think this is what's going on here.  If I change the code to be "class A<T extends Base>" where Base is some other class I've declared it still works

Comment: @MattWallace I think what I said it still holds. When you change to `A<T extends Base>`, your method accepting `A<? extends Comparable<?>>` is placing additional restrictions on the parameterized type of `A`. `A`'s parameterized type must extend `Base` AND extend `Comparable<?>`. Maybe it would be clearer to emphasize that `A<? extends Comparable<Double>>` is *not* compatible with `A<T extends String>`

Comment: @Samuel I apologize it have been a year since you answered the question, but still, could you explain what the phrase from the specification you quoted means. In particular, I don't understand what exactly _**under** the reflexive and transitive closure_ means. It is usually said that a set is **closed under** operation, but here it sounds like **a set is under a closure**. Any references would be also very appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @AndriySimonov If you apply the given rules to the type arguments you'll have a relation, you should then take the reflexive and transitive closure of that relation and check if the first relation is a subset of the second. I created a gist to describe my understanding of that clause of the spec with an example. I'm no expert on set theory, but I hope it helps some https://gist.github.com/s-nel/5566df46345581b8cfa13cdc0e5692bb