# How do I do generic generics?

Tags: java, generics, generic-programming, generic-list

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
class GenericInseption{
  public static void main(String[] args){
    LinkedList<LinkedList<Dad>> listOfLists = new LinkedList<>();
    LinkedList<Dad> list = new LinkedList<>();
    listOfLists.add(list);
    test(listOfLists);//error
  }
  private static void test(LinkedList<LinkedList<? extends Person>> listOfLists){
    for(LinkedList<? extends Person> list : listOfLists){
      for(Person person : list){
        //peform operation on person objects
      }
    }
  }
}
class Person{}
class Dad extends Person{}
```

error

```
GenericInseption.java:7: error: method test in class GenericInseption cannot be applied to given types;
    test(listOfLists);//error
    ^
  required: LinkedList<LinkedList<? extends Person>>
  found: LinkedList<LinkedList<Dad>>
  reason: argument mismatch; LinkedList<LinkedList<Dad>> cannot be converted to LinkedList<LinkedList<? extends Person>>
1 error
```

but LinkedList< Dad> is a subtype of LinkedList< ? extends Person>

How is this supposed to work?

Comment: You _would_ need `LinkedList<? extends LinkedList<? extends Person>>`.

Comment: thank you Louis this seemed to work

Comment: Or just `List<? extends List<? extends Person>>`

Comment: yes Paul I see I don't use any of LinkedList's special members in the method it could simply be List

Comment: Everybody has difficulties with this to start with. Java generics are probably too complicated. Here's a similar question I asked a while ago. http://stackoverflow.com/q/27465348/3973077

Answer (score 6):

Even though `LinkedList<Dad>` is a subtype of `LinkedList<? extends Person>`, a `LinkedList<LinkedList<Dad>>` is not a subtype of `LinkedList<LinkedList<? extends Person>>`, for the same reason that a `List<Dog>` is not a subtype of `List<Animal>` -- Java's generics are invariant.  In this case, they are invariant at each level, not just at the `? extends Person` level but at the `LinkedList<? extends Person>` level.

Add another wildcard in front of `LinkedList` in the first level of generics in the `test` method.

```
//                                  vvvvvvvvv
private static void test(LinkedList<? extends LinkedList<? extends Person>> listOfLists){
```

Or, to make it more broadly applicable, use `List` instead of `LinkedList`:

```
private static void test(List<? extends List<? extends Person>> listOfLists){
    for(List<? extends Person> list : listOfLists){
```

Comment: yes it works I _think_ I get it now because subtyping in generics is different than normal subtyping