# Nested wildcard generics variable affectation

Tags: java, generics, java-7, nested-generics

Given the following Java code:

```
public class Test {
    public static class A<T> {
        private T t;

        public A(T t) {
            this.t = t;
        }

        public T getT() {
            return t;
        }

        public void setT(T t) {
            this.t = t;
        }
    }

    public static class B<T> {
        private T t;

        public B(T t) {
            this.t = t;
        }

        public T getT() {
            return t;
        }

        public void setT(T t) {
            this.t = t;
        }
    }

    public static class F<T> {
        private T t;

        public F(T t) {
            this.t = t;
        }

        public A<B<T>> construct() {
            return new A<>(new B<>(t));
        }

        public T getT() {
            return t;
        }

        public void setT(T t) {
            this.t = t;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        F<?> f = new F<>(0);
        // 1: KO
        // A<B<?>> a = f.construct();
        // 2: KO
        // A<B<Object>> a = f.construct();
        // 3: OK
        // A<?> a = f.construct();
    }
}
```

In the main method of the `Test` class, what is the correct type of a variable that will receive the result of `f.construct()` ?
This type should be something like `A<B<...>>` where `...` is what I'm looking for.

There are 3 commented lines of code above which represent my attempts to solve this problem.
The first and second lines aren't valid.
The third is but I loose the `B` type information and I have to cast `a.getT()`.

Comment: Why are you using `F<?> f = new F<>(0);` instead of, for example, `F<Integer> f = new F<>(0);`

Comment: Because `f` will not always be affected with instances of `F<Integer>`.

Comment: You're passing 0 as argument. Which is an `int`.

Comment: It's an example, `Integer` can be replaced with any type.

Comment: I can't check right now but I think `A<? extends B<?>> a = f.construct();` is what you want.

Comment: @PaulBoddington: you're right, it compiles.

Comment: Just remember that when you nest generics you usuallt need a ? at every level.

Comment: Thanks. If you answer the question, I can accept it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/27465348/3973077

Comment: I can't really answer properly as I'm on my mobile. Don't worry about the points. I'm glad I could help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`A<? extends B<?>> a = f.construct();` is the right syntax, as stated by Paul Boddington.