# How to sort a Collection of generic Pairs

Tags: java, sorting

This is homework, so I would prefer some explanation rather than just giving me the answer.

I have a generic Pair class that can take any key value K, and any value V.

The goal is to write a generic method:

`public static <...> Collection<Pair<...>> sortPairCollection(Collection <Pair<....>> col)`

The only other guideline is that the K type must implement Comparable<...>.

After some digging, I saw people recommend something like this:

```
public static Collection<Pair<?,?>> sortPairCollection(Collection<Pair<?,?>> col)
{
    Collections.sort(col, new Comparator<Pair<?,?>>(){
        @Override
        public int compare(Pair<?, ?> x, Pair<?, ?> y) {
            return (Integer)x.v() - (Integer)y.v();
        }
    });
}
```

But that doesn't work for me, I get an error that says the sort method is not applicable to those parameters. I don't really know where to go from here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Collections.sort` only works on `List` instances, not on general `Collections`. It does not make sense to sort a `HashSet` for example.

Secondly, due to arithmetic overflow, you should avoid using subtraction in a comparator like that. It is always better to use `Integer.compare`.

Also, a method with return type `Collection<Pair<?,?>>` must return something. You could return `col`, but as you are mutating `col` it makes more sense to make the method `void`.

Another point is that it looks like your method will throw a `ClassCastException` unless the second type parameter is `Integer` (I am assuming `v()` has return type `V`). If this is the case, there is no point writing your method for `Pair<?, ?>` as you could just use `Pair<?, Integer>`.

Finally, due to the way generics work in Java, you won't actually be able to pass in a `List<Pair<String, Integer>>` with your current signature, because a `List<Pair<String, Integer>>` is *not* a `List<Pair<?, Integer>>` (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2745265/3973077) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27465348/3973077)). If you want to be able to do that, the argument should have type `List<? extends Pair<?, Integer>>`.

**Edit**

I now realise that I haven't really answered the question. The idea is not to mutate the original collection, but return a new one. Also the sorting should be done by key, not value, because `K` must implement `Comparable`.

In order to use the `compareTo` method, you need to indicate that `K extends Comparable`. The way to do this is to use the signature

```
public static <K extends Comparable<? super K>, V> Collection<Pair<K, V>> sortPairCollection(Collection<Pair<K, V>> col)
```

This is a bit of a mouthful - generics have significantly increased the complexity of method signatures.

`K extends Comparable<? super K>` says that `K`s can be compared with other `K`s.

You will still need to use a `List` though. You could use the `ArrayList` constructor that accepts a `Collection`.

As requested, I'll leave it up to you to write the correct code.

Comment: Also, the method declares to return `Collection<Pair<?,?>>` but in fact does not.

Comment: @Tunaki You're right about that. I never got around to that yet since I was trying to figure out the sorting first.

Comment: @Tunaki Thanks, I missed that.

Comment: I have two problems with this answer. 1) You don't cover *"K type must implement Comparable<...>"*. To me, it implies that the sorting should sort the pairs by the key, not by the value. 2) If the *"goal is to write [the shown] generic method"*, you can do it. The reason it returns a `Collection` is that it should not mutate the parameter, which is also why it's ok for the parameter to be a `Collection` and not a `List`.

Comment: @Andreas You're right. I didn't actually notice the part about `K`. I was too busy analysing the code I missed the entire point of the question. I'll edit.

Comment: I otherwise like your answer. Maybe help OP by showing the completed method signature, where the first `<...>` should be `<K extends Comparable<K>, V>`?

Comment: @Andreas Thanks for that. I just added a `? super`.

Comment: Thank you for all of your help. I was getting close to the answer before the edit but apparently I was missing the `? super` part of `? super K`. Code works perfectly now.

Comment: Glad to hear it. In almost all cases you don't need to use `? super`, but it's best to include it anyway. This says that Ks can be compared with instances of a type that could actually be larger than K. However in practice there are few real examples of different classes that are mutually comparable.

Answer (score -1):

Here is the complete program:

```
public static <K extends Comparable<? super K>, V extends Comparable<? super V>> void sortPairCollection(List<Pair<K, V>> col){

        Collections.sort(col, new Comparator<Pair<K,V>>(){

            public int compare(Pair<K, V> o1, Pair<K, V> o2) {

                int keyflag = o1.getValue().compareTo(o2.getValue()) == 0 ? o1.getKey().compareTo(o2.getKey()): o1.getValue().compareTo(o2.getValue()) ;

                return keyflag;

            }});

    }
```

Comment: clearly stated in the question: so I would prefer some explanation rather than just giving me the answer.   so this is not an answer